# How to validate whether the given email address belongs to a corporate company?

Tags: java

How can I validate the email address entered belongs to a corporate company when the user enters his/her mail address.

The requirement is not to accept the public emails like gmail or yahoo etc, and to only accept the email id of a CORPORATE(xyx@companyname.com)

Comment: That wouldn't be possible. You would have to know the domains of all corporate companies to do such a look up. (Not my down-vote though).

Comment: You need to know the domain address of mail server of the company.

Comment: There may be a way of doing it, but we need to know what you class as corporate.

Comment: the requirement is not to accept the public emails like gmail or yahoo etc only accept the email id of a CORPORATE(xyx@companyname.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep a manual list of what all companies do you treat as CORPORATE, i feel the requirement is not to accept the public emails like gmail or yahoo, so may be you can keep two lists one for supported and one for unspported and keep them maintained :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, You have understood my requirement exactly, we have discussed what exactly you have written, my question is "don't we have any third party tool or any other medium to validate this?". Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: @Anto i tried searching but couldnt locate anything that suits the requirement , may be you can maintain a list of all the non allowed emails , which generally people do for the custom requirements they have :)

Answer (score 0):

You can using tow step email validation. First take user mail and send for it email a confirmation email, if your second email send correctly and user response to it, you know user email is valid. There are many web site that use this approach for activation account and validation email.

Also above suggestion it is better that you will validate pattern of input email by `Regular Expression`.

following urls may help you:

- http://www.emailanswers.com/services/email-list-cleaning/
- http://www.massmailsoftware.com/verify/

I hope my answer is useful for you.